# $\mathbb{F}_2(x)$ is not separable in the field $\mathbb{F}_2(x^2)$

Tags: galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I need to show

$\mathbb{F}_2(x)$ is not separable in the field $\mathbb{F}_2(x^2)$.
Here is what I know so far : char($\mathbb{F_2}$)=2 and we have that it is a perfect field. I also know that any irreducible polynomial on a perfect field is separable.

Can anyone help?

Comment: so you don't know the definition of a separable extension ?

Comment: @mercio seperable if all its roots are simple.

Comment: What is the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $\mathbb{F}_2(x^2)$ ? Is this polynomial separable (what is its formal derivative) ?

Comment: Is the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $\mathbb{F}_2(x^2) = x^2?$ Thus we have $(2x, x^2)=x$, no it is not separable?

Comment: Not quite. Note that if you want minimal polynomials of algebraic elements over $\Bbb F_2(x^2)$, then $x$ _cannot_ be the variable you use. You have to use another, like $t$. So the minimal polynomial is, for instance, $t^2-x^2$.

Comment: so  $(t^2-x^2, 2t)=t$. Then it only shows that $f(t)=t^2-x^2$ is not separable in $\mathbb{F}_2(x)$. Then what?

Comment: @Arthur what should I do

Comment: What is the derivative of $f$ (with respect to $t$)? What is the definition of "separable"? Do those fit together? Alternatively, over the algebraic closure of $\Bbb F_2(x^2)$, we have $f(t) = (x+t)(x-t) = (x+t)^2$, which clearly has multiple roots.

Comment: Things will be much clearer if you set $x^2=t$ and show that $\Bbb F_2(\sqrt{t\,}\,)$ is inseparable over $\Bbb F_2(t)$.